# Distributional derivative of Weierstrass function

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

How can we compute the distributional derivative of the Weierstrass function 
$$W(x) =\sum_{k=1}^\infty \lambda^{(s-2)k}\sin(\lambda^k x)$$
where $s \in (0,2)$ and $\lambda$ are fixed parameters?

We know that the Weierstrass function is nowhere differentiable. This implies that it does not have a weak derivative. However, since $W \in L^1_{loc}$, we can consider the associated distribution $T_W$ and compute its distributional derivative.

I'm having troubles doing that computation because of the series representation of $W$.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense as written. What are you actually trying to do, what tools do you have available, and what is the motivation?

Comment: @T.Bongers Sorry, there was a typo (that is, I had mistakenly deleted the main verb of the sentence).

Comment: I'm glad you edited it to fix that, but it doesn't address 2 of the 3 issues in my comment; since this is not a do-my-homework site, please [edit] the question to *actually* improve it.

Comment: @T.Bongers Done.

Comment: You have two parameters: $s$ and $\lambda$. How is $W$ a function just of $x$?

Comment: @TedShifrin We take those parameters to be fixed.

Comment: Why do you think the function is nowhere differentiable? I think this should only be true if $s\in (0,1]$ but not if $s\in (1,2)$.

Comment: @Shalop Why is that?

Comment: Sorry I meant the other way, it’s differentiable if s is in (0,1) but not if s is in [1,2). That’s because the series of derivatives converges uniformly in the former case

Answer (score 4):

For some $r \in (1/2,1)$ let

$$W(x) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty r^m e^{2i\pi 2^m x}$$

The series converges uniformly to a continuous function and for any $\phi \in C^\infty(\Bbb{R/Z})$ smooth $1$-periodic $$\langle W,\phi \rangle = \int_0^1 W(x)\phi(x)dx = \sum_{m=0}^\infty r^m \hat{\phi}(-2^m), \qquad \hat{\phi}(n) = \langle e^{-2i \pi n x},\phi \rangle$$
Which defines a distribution $W \in D'(\Bbb{R/Z})$.

Then

$$W^{(k)}(x) = \lim_{M\to \infty}(2i\pi)^k\sum_{m=0}^M (2^k r)^m  e^{2i\pi 2^m x}$$
(with the limit taken in the sense of distribution)

defines a distribution

$$\langle W^{(k)},\phi \rangle = (2i\pi)^k\sum_{m=0}^\infty (2^k r)^m \hat{\phi}(-2^m)$$
the series converges absolutely since $\hat{\phi}(n) = O(n^{-l})$ for every $l$.

Comment: Thank you. 1. Why can we rewrite $W(x)$ in that way for some $r \in (1/2, 1)$? 2.  Why can we take $\phi \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ instead of just $\phi \in  C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$? 3. What did you deduce the decay of $\hat \phi$ from? 4. Can we rewrite the series in the last formula in a more explicit way?

Comment: If you want to consider $W$ as a distribution on $\Bbb{R}$ then $\langle W,\varphi \rangle_\Bbb{R} = \langle W, P \varphi \rangle_\Bbb{R/Z}$ where $P \varphi(x) = \sum_n \varphi(x+n)$, so it doesn't change anything (as $P$ is a continuous linear map $ C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R}) \to  C^\infty(\Bbb{R/Z})$), equivalently replace the Fourier series coefficients of $\phi$ by the Fourier transform of $\varphi$.

Comment: The faster-than-polynomial decay of Fourier coefficients of smooth functions is well-known : $|\hat{\phi}(n) (2i\pi n)^l| \le \|\phi^{(l)}\|_{L^1(0,1)}$

Comment: anything unclear ?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Why is it true that there exists $r \in (1/2,1)$ such that
$W(x) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty r^m e^{2i\pi 2^m x}$? Could you add some details on that?

Comment: Come on you are supposed to look at $Im(W(x))$.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Don't see how to go from $ \sum_{m=0}^\infty r^m e^{2i\pi 2^m x}$ to $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \lambda^{(s-2)k}\sin(\lambda^k x)$ ??

Comment: I don't. How do you do it?

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ as in the quotient ring?